# Why is the region growing implementation not working properly?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Region growing is a simple region-based image segmentation method. It is also classified as a pixel-based image segmentation method since it involves the selection of initial seed points.I wrote the following in matlab and there seems to be a infinite loop apparently.I wish to know where the implementation is failing.

```
import java.util.LinkedList
a=imread('C:\Users\hpw\Desktop\1.jpeg');

s=size(a);
visited=zeros(s(1),s(2));
x=179;
y=180;
%seed chosen
visited(179,180)=1;
boundaryx = LinkedList();
boundaryy = LinkedList();
boundaryx.add(x);
boundaryy.add(y);


while(boundaryx.size()>0 &&boundaryy.size()>0)
   nextx=boundaryx.pop();
   nexty=boundaryy.pop();
   if(a(nextx,nexty)>110)
       visited(nextx,nexty)=2;
   end
   %taking 4 neighbors only
   if(nextx>1 && nexty>1)%right neighbor
       if(visited(nextx+1,nexty)==0)
           boundaryx.add(nextx+1);
           boundaryy.add(nexty);
       end
       if(visited(nextx-1,nexty)==0)
           boundaryx.add(nextx+1);
           boundaryy.add(nexty);
       end
       if(visited(nextx,nexty+1)==0)
           boundaryx.add(nextx+1);
           boundaryy.add(nexty);
       end
       if(visited(nextx+1,nexty-1)==0)
           boundaryx.add(nextx+1);
           boundaryy.add(nexty);
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always get a problem like that when using the `while` loop. Try implementing the condition at which it's out of bounds. Or implement a condition at which the you `break;` out of the loop.

Like something like this right at before the `end %while`:

```
if boundaryy.size() >= 1000 && boundaryx.size() >= 1000
   break;
end
```

It's maybe not the condition you search for but this loop was infinite until I set a condition at which while can `break;`. If you look at your boundary condition for your `while` loop you can see that `boundaryy.size()>0` is ALWAYS true. This leads to another Method to stop the `while` loop without `break;`.

```
while(boundaryx.size()<1000 &&boundaryy.size()<1000) 
...
end
```

This way the `boundaryy.size()` and `boundaryx.size()` will eventually increase and reach the boundary condition `1000`.

Hope this helps :)